# Integrate Azure AD B2C service with .net core web API

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

I want to implement Azure AD B2C with .net core web API application.
The purpose of Web API application, to create/register users, provide bearer token, also when a new user create/register in Azure ADb2c the same entry it will create in SQL DB also.

The Web API application will be accessed by other .Net core web site applications, Android APK, IOS APP.

Using AD B2C how the sign-in/sign up will be handle by Web API with the other application.
Similarly how to get the bearer token and pass to Postman to test/run Web API with Authorize attribute.

Can anyone please guide me on how to implement it with a sample of code.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The Web API's are be used to protect and accept the B2C access tokens from client applications.

You can implement Azure AD B2C .Net Core MVC web application with web api.
Please go through the available [code samples](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-aspnetcore-webapp-openidconnect-v2) which can help you more.
In the web API using the Access token you can connect with [Microsoft Graph API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/manage-user-accounts-graph-api) using which you can create Users.

Please go through the documentation on how to [expose you API service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/tutorial-web-api-dotnet?tabs=app-reg-ga#configure-scopes)